# AccountManager: when to set result?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, accountmanager, android-account

## Context

My app only stores user/pass. No tokens are used.

## Question 1

Methods [`setAccountAuthenticatorResult(Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.html#setAccountAuthenticatorResult(android.os.Bundle)) and [`onResult(Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorResponse.html#onResult(android.os.Bundle)) are meant to notify the [`AbstractAccountAuthenticator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator) about the outcome, but I have a project working without them, what are they for ?

## Question 2

What is [`onRequestContinued()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorResponse#onrequestcontinued) for ?

## Question 3

When [`addAccount`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#addaccount) is finished and the account created, should `onActivityResult` be called on the `Activity` that triggered it?

## Question 4

If an `Intent` is returned with key [`AccountManager.KEY_INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#key_intent) in [`addAccount`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator#addaccount) implementation, the [`AbstractAccountAuthenticator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator) will start the `Intent`. I have noticed that many developers add extras. Who gets them ?

```
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);

    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);     // <-- this
    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);      // <-- this
    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);   // <-- this


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);

    return bundle;
}
```

---

## Asnwers

**kris larson**:

Thanks for the answer. I think we might be using the `AccountManager` wrong to be honest.

We want to share some credentials across our apps, so we have a `Service` to hold the custom *account type*. Since apps know the *account type* and share the signing certificate, they have access to the `Account`.

When each app is started, they try to get the `Account`. If no `Account` exists, they trigger the login page in our `Service` by calling `AccountManager.addAccount(...)`.

Once the login (through web services) is successfull, we make it available to other apps with `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(...)`. Not setting an outcome after it, does not impact the outcome.

How does it affect the `AccountManager` ? Is this approach correct ?

Comment: one question at a time please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Methods setAccountAuthenticatorResult(Bundle) and onResult(Bundle) are meant to notify the AbstractAccountAuthenticator about the outcome, but I have a project working without them, what are they for ?

Those methods (as well as `onError`) are to pass back a result to whoever might wait for one, e.g. have a look at `AccountManager.getAuthToken(...)` and many others that let you specify a `AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>`. This is where your result will be passed to. `null` is valid for the callback, so unless you structure your app around the result, it will work without it.

`AccountAuthenticatorResponse.onResult(Bundle)` and `onError(...)` are much more important if you implement `getAuthToken` where this is how you can return an access token from an asynchronous backend call (e.g. token refresh).

> What is onRequestContinued() for ?

There is very little information (reads: none) available. The only time it gets used that I could find was in `AccountManagerService` where it's but a counter that gets increased for logging purposes. I don't think it does anything at the moment.

> When addAccount is finished and the account created, should onActivityResult be called on the Activity that triggered it?

Should work as long as you use `startActivityForResult(..)`

> If an Intent is returned with key AccountManager.KEY_INTENT in addAccount implementation, the AbstractAccountAuthenticator will start the Intent. I have noticed that many developers add extras. Who gets them ?

As already mentioned by kris, you can return an Intent that starts your Activity and pass any extras that you might need.

---

On an unrelated note: You should really try not to store any passwords in plain text. Even though the AccountManager says `setPassword()` it is not protected and thus not secure.

Comment: `AccountAuthenticatorResponse.onResult(Bundle) and onError(...) are much more important if you implement getAuthToken where this is how you can return an access token from an asynchronous backend call` I guess that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I'll just describe how — after much agony — I implemented the authentication service for our app.

You said you have a `Service` for the authenticator.  I'll assume you did that in the prescribed way: declare a service in your manifest that references your class, which subclasses `android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator`.  The manifest entry also references an XML file with the `account-authenticator` tag that declares your account type, plus a name and icons to be used by the Settings | Accounts page.  That stuff is all documented.

For our app, I wanted the last signed in user to sign in automatically until they selected "Sign Out" on the navigation drawer.  To accomplish this, the username would be persisted in `SharedPreferences` for the app.

So if the `SharedPreferences` did *not* have a username, the app calls `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()` for our custom account type, then calls `startActivityForResult` with intent that was returned.  If the user selects "Add new account", then `addAccount()` will be invoked on the authenticator as described below.

Our authentication activity not only has UI for username/password login but also password reset and new trial account creation, so there are a lot of moving parts.  When the user enters the username/password and presses the Sign In button, the app authenticates against our server.  If successful, the app calls `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly()` for that username.

The `AccountManager` Choose Account activity will call `onActivityResult()` when this is all finished.  If we get `RESULT_OK` the app persists the username for the next sign in operation.

If the `SharedPreferences` has a username, and the Account Manager has an account registered for it, we don't need to select anything and just skip to this next phase.

With the account selected/known, now the app can authenticate.  It calls `peekAuthToken()` to see if a token was registered, and `invalidateAuthToken()` if it was.  This is done so that when the app calls `getAuthToken()` on the account manager, it forces the account manager to call `getAuthToken()` on the app's authenticator to authenticate with the server.  Since the server is not returning tokens, we are using dummy tokens and that is why they are invalidated every time.

Now the interesting part about all this is that if the user selects an account that was already registered, it won't be authenticated, whereas if they selected Add New Account and that operation was successful, the new account will be authenticated.  So just be aware that if you notice that signing into a new account causes *two* round trips to your authentication server, now you know why.  (I have some logic in there using `setUserData()` on the account to indicate pre-authenticated, but it looks like I forgot to finish that feature.  Hmmm.)

---

Let's start with some background to clarify things.

You have some subclass of `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`.  You have created this class to respond to authentication requests for the account type it was registered for.  The thing to keep in mind about this class is that the platform `AccountManager` is always the component your app will interact with; your app will never interact directly with this class.  So in a sense the `AccountManager` is a client of your authentication service.  The work that the authenticator performs is stuff that will be in a background thread.

Now part of the work the authentication service must do is interact with the user, asking for user account names, passwords, fingerprint IDs, smart cards, etc.  So let's assume you have an `AuthenticatorActivity` that does that work.  Typically you will subclass `android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorActivity` for this.  This activity class is really nothing special.  The only thing it does is to expect a reference to an `AccountAuthenticatorResponse` when it starts, then to call that response's `onResult()` method when the activity exits.

The app I work on is similar to yours in that there is no token returned from the authentication service.  I still implemented `getAuthToken` for two reasons:

- to stay consistent to the workflow that Google has mandated.
- to make it easy to return a real token if/when we enhance our authentication service to return a token.

So let's follow the bouncing ball to understand how everything fits together.

- Your app activity has implemented the `AccountManagerCallback` interface in order to get asynchronous messages from the `AccountManager`.
- Let's assume your app has persisted a user name for authentication.  Your app creates an `Account` object with this username.
- Optionally your app can call `AccountManager.getAccountsByType()` to ensure that the account exists.
- Your app calls `AccountManager.getAuthToken()` for the account.
- The `AccountManager` sees that your authenticator is registered for that account type and calls authenticator's `getAuthToken` method.
- The `getAuthToken` method will contact your authentication server and get a response.
- If successful, your authenticator returns the (dummy) auth token.

If the login fails, then things get interesting.

- Since your authenticator is not returning an auth token, it must return an intent to start your `AuthenticatorActivity` so that the user can re-authenticate.
- The `AccountManager` uses your intent to start your `AuthenticatorActivity`. As part of the request, it will get a reference to an `AccountAuthenticatorResponse` it will need later.
- Your `AuthenticatorActivity` interacts with the user, gets username/password, contacts your server, gets a response.  Let's say the authentication succeeds.
- Your activity will finish, calling the `onResult` method of the `AccountAuthenticatorResponse` it was given.
- The `AccountManager` on getting notification from the response object will invoke the callback method with the results.

So with that we can answer your questions:

> Methods `setAccountAuthenticatorResult(Bundle)` and `onResult(Bundle)` are meant to notify the `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` about the outcome, but I have a project working without them, what are they for ?

More correctly, they are meant to notify the `AccountManager` about the outcome. 
 Are you sure it's working?  Have you tried logging in with an invalid username/password?  `AccountManager` will assume authentication has been cancelled unless it gets notified otherwise.

> What is `onRequestContinued()` for ?

I don't have an exact answer. My guess is that it's to keep the `AccountManager` in sync somehow with what is happening with the UI in regards to authentication.

> If an `Intent` is returned with key `AccountManager.KEY_INTENT` in `addAccount` implementation, the `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` will start the Intent. I have noticed that many developers add extras. Who gets them ?

The answer is:  You do.  This intent will go the `AuthenticatorActivity` that you have created to handle authentication, so any data your activity needs to perform authentication needs to be passed in with these extras.

> When `addAccount` is finished and the account created, should `onActivityResult` be called on the `Activity` that triggered it?

The use case for this is when your app calls `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()` then calls `startActivityForResult()` with the resulting intent.  The `AccountManager`'s "choose account" activity is then started.

Now since "add new account" is an option on the "choose account" UI, the `AccountManager` will call your authenticator's `addAccount()` method when that option is selected.  Your authenticator then returns a `Bundle` as described in the `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` docs back to `AccountManager`.  After this the "choose account" activity will finish and call `onActivityResult()` on your activity.

Hopefully you're starting to see that the `AccountManager` acts as a broker between your app and your authenticator components.  To make this clearer, consider that you could package up those components in a way that *other apps* could use them to authenticate to your service without knowing any details.  If you created your own custom account type, you can invoke your authentication directly from the Settings | Accounts page of the device.  This is a good test to see if your `addAccount()` method is implemented correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I added an update to the post to clarify some points :D

Comment: I updated my answer.  `AccountManager` is a real minefield; hope the info is helpful.